# Transport date and time between Javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime

I'm developing an application which deals with date and time in frontend, with Javascript's Date object, and sends this information to the API based on C#... So far I'm thinking about converting the date and time selected by the user in the frontend using the `getTime()` function, so I can get its milliseconds and then convert to DateTime in C# with the following function

```
 public static DateTime GetDateFromMilliseconds(double unixTimeStamp)
    { 
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }
```

So, I'd like to know, is there another better way to deal with it?

Comment: ISO8601 is your friend.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of C# include methods for working with Unix timestamps.
For this case, using `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()` will save you a few lines of code.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0